# how to solve following error of php?

Tags: ee2, php, error

Hello friends i am using magento and expression engine both in my site and for integration expression engine with magento i am using one module mage_integratee in that php file i get following error so how i can solve this errors

```
1)
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: store
Filename: mage_integratee/ext.mage_integratee.php
Line Number: 138

2) 
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: exclude
Filename: mage_integratee/ext.mage_integratee.php
Line Number: 153

3)
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: require_once(/home/hst/domains/hst.uldev.co/public_html/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: mage_integratee/ext.mage_integratee.php
Line Number: 177

4)
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/hst/domains/hst.uldev.co/public_html/Mage.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/hst/domains/hst.uldev.co/public_html/a/system/expressionengine/third_party/mage_integratee/ext.mage_integratee.php on line 177
```

i am using following php code in mage_integratee.php file

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mage_integratee_ext {

    var $name       = 'Mage Integratee';
    var $version        = '2.0.3';
    var $description    = 'Integrate Magento Layouts into ExpressionEngine Pages';
    var $settings_exist = 'y';
    var $docs_url       = ''; // 'http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/';

    var $settings        = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param   mixed   Settings array or empty string if none exist.
     */
    function __construct($settings='')
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }
    // END

    /**
     * Activate Extension
     *
     * This function enters the extension into the exp_extensions table
     *
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html for
     * more information on the db class.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function activate_extension()
    {
        $this->settings = array(
            'mage'   => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
            'head'  => 'y',
            'after_body_start'  => 'y',
            'global_notices'  => 'y',
            'header'  => 'y',
            'global_messages'  => 'y',
            'left'  => 'y',
            'right'  => 'y',
            'footer'  => 'y',
            'before_body_end'  => 'y'
        );


        $data = array(
            'class'     => __CLASS__,
            'method'    => 'init_layout',
            'hook'      => 'template_fetch_template',
            'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority'  => 10,
            'version'   => $this->version,
            'enabled'   => 'y'
        );

        ee()->db->insert('extensions', $data);
    }
    // END

    /**
     * Update Extension
     *
     * This function performs any necessary db updates when the extension
     * page is visited
     *
     * @return  mixed   void on update / false if none
     */
    function update_extension($current = '')
    {
        if ($current == '' OR $current == $this->version)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ($current < '2.0.0')
        {
            // Update to version 1.0
        }

        ee()->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
        ee()->db->update(
                    'extensions',
                    array('version' => $this->version)
        );
    }
    // END

    /**
     * Disable Extension
     *
     * This method removes information from the exp_extensions table
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function disable_extension()
    {
        ee()->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
        ee()->db->delete('extensions');
    }
    // END

    // --------------------------------
    //  Settings
    // --------------------------------

    function settings()
    {
        $settings = array();

        $settings['mage']      = array('i', '', "");
        $settings['store']      = array('i', '', "");
        $settings['exclude']      = array('i', '', "");
        $settings['head']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['after_body_start']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['global_notices']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['header']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['global_messages']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['left']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['right']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['footer']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');
        $settings['before_body_end']      = array('r', array('y' => "Yes", 'n' => "No"), 'y');

        return $settings;
    }
    // END

    // --------------------------------
    //  Initialize Layout
    // --------------------------------

    function init_layout($row)
    {

        $mageRunCode = $this->settings['store'];
        $mageRunType = "store";

        if(isset( ee()->config->_global_vars['MAGE_INTEGRATEE_RUN_CODE']))
        {
            $mageRunCode = ee()->config->_global_vars['MAGE_INTEGRATEE_RUN_CODE'];
        }

        if(isset( ee()->config->_global_vars['MAGE_INTEGRATEE_RUN_TYPE']))
        {
            $mageRunType = ee()->config->_global_vars['MAGE_INTEGRATEE_RUN_TYPE'];
        }

        //print_r(ee()->config);

        if($this->settings['exclude'] != "")
        {
            if (strpos($this->settings['exclude'], $row['group_name']) !== FALSE)
            {
                return $row;
            }
        }

        if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'mage'))
        {

            if($this->settings['mage'] === ""){
                return $row;
            } else {
              $mage = $this->settings['mage'];
            }

            if($mage[strlen($mage)-1] !== "/"){
                $mage .= "/Mage.php";
            } else {
                $mage .= "Mage.php";
            }

            //Initialize Magento
            require_once $mage;
            Mage::app($mageRunCode,$mageRunType);
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

            //Check if logged in
            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->IsLoggedIn()){ 
                //Load Layout Handles
                $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
                $layout->getUpdate()
                    ->addHandle('default')
                    ->addHandle('expressionengine_integratee')
                    ->addHandle('customer_logged_in')
                    ->load();
            }
            else
            { 
                //Load Layout Handles
                $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
                $layout->getUpdate()
                    ->addHandle('default')
                    ->addHandle('expressionengine_integratee')
                    ->addHandle('customer_logged_out')
                    ->load();
            }

            //Generate Blocks
            $layout->generateXml()
                ->generateBlocks();

            ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'mage', '1');

            //Load Block Output and Create Global Variables
            if($this->settings['head'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'head'))
                {
                    $head = $layout->getBlock('head')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $head = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $head);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:head'] = $head;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'head', $head);
                } else {
                    $head = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'head');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:head'] = $head;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['after_body_start'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'after_body_start'))
                {
                    $after_body_start = $layout->getBlock('after_body_start')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $after_body_start = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $after_body_start);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:after_body_start'] = $after_body_start;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'after_body_start', $after_body_start);
                } else {
                    $after_body_start = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'after_body_start');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:after_body_start'] = $after_body_start;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['global_notices'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_notices'))
                {
                    $global_notices = $layout->getBlock('global_notices')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $global_notices = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $global_notices);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:global_notices'] = $global_notices;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'global_notices', $global_notices);
                } else {
                    $global_notices = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_notices');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:global_notices'] = $global_notices;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['header'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'header'))
                {
                    $header = $layout->getBlock('header')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $header = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $header);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:header'] = $header;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'header', $header);
                } else {
                    $header = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'header');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:header'] = $header;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['global_messages'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_messages'))
                {
                    $global_messages = $layout->getBlock('global_messages')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $global_messages = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $global_messages);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:global_messages'] = $global_messages;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'global_messages', $global_messages);
                } else {
                    $global_messages = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_messages');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:global_messages'] = $global_messages;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['left'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'left'))
                {
                    $left = $layout->getBlock('left')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $left = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $left);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:left'] = $left;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'left', $left);
                } else {
                    $left = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'left');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:left'] = $left;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['right'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'right'))
                {
                    $right = $layout->getBlock('right')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $right = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $right);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:right'] = $right;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'right', $right);
                } else {
                    $right = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'right');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:right'] = $right;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['footer'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'footer'))
                {
                    $footer = $layout->getBlock('footer')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $footer = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $footer);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:footer'] = $footer;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'footer', $footer);
                } else {
                    $footer = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'footer');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:footer'] = $footer;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['before_body_end'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'before_body_end'))
                {
                    $before_body_end = $layout->getBlock('before_body_end')->setTitle("")->toHtml();
                    $before_body_end = str_replace('?___SID=U', '', $before_body_end);
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:before_body_end'] = $before_body_end;
                    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'before_body_end', $before_body_end);
                } else {
                    $before_body_end = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'before_body_end');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:before_body_end'] = $before_body_end;
                }

            }

            return $row;

        } else {

            //Load Block Output and Create Global Variables
            if($this->settings['head'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'head'))
                {                  
                    $head = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'head');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:head'] = $head;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['after_body_start'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'after_body_start'))
                {
                    $after_body_start = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'after_body_start');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:after_body_start'] = $after_body_start;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['global_notices'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_notices'))
                {
                    $global_notices = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_notices');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:global_notices'] = $global_notices;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['header'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'header'))
                {
                    $header = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'header');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:header'] = $header;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['global_messages'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_messages'))
                {
                    $global_messages = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'global_messages');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:global_messages'] = $global_messages;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['left'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'left'))
                {
                    $left = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'left');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:left'] = $left;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['right'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'right'))
                {
                    $right = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'right');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:right'] = $right;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['footer'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'footer'))
                {
                    $footer = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'footer');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:footer'] = $footer;
                }

            }
            if($this->settings['before_body_end'] === "y"){

                if ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'before_body_end'))
                {
                    $before_body_end = ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'before_body_end');
                    ee()->config->_global_vars['mage:before_body_end'] = $before_body_end;
                }

            }

            return $row;
        }
    }
    // END

}
// END CLASS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two errors, you need open the extension's setting in the CP and setup all parameters.

For errors 3 & 4, check if your server path to Mage.php is correct.